# select data from two table where id = auth user id (i am using laravel 8)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I want to select the data from the action_user users actions tables but where user_id in action_user table is equal to Auth user id to get just the data of this user

**here is my code**

**here is the query I am try to get the data by it**

```
 @php
        $user = auth()->id();

        $total = DB::table('action_users')
            ->join('users', '$user', 'action_users.user_id')
            ->join('actions', 'actions.id', 'action_users.action_id')
            ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.email', 'action_users.point', 'actions.action_title', 'actions.action_image', 'action_users.created_at')
            ->groupBy('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.email', 'action_users.point', 'actions.action_title', 'actions.action_image', 'action_users.created_at')
            ->get();

        dd($total);
    @endphp
```

**here is action_user model**

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'admin_id',
        'user_id',
        'action_id',
        'point',
    ];
    
     public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
    }

    public function action(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Action::class,'action_id','id');
    }
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your approach... You should have 2 Models, `User` and `Action`, with a `belongsToMany()` relationship between the 2. You don't define a model for the Pivot Table (`ActionUser`) unless you have a reason to. Additionally, `DB::table(...)` doesn't use Models at all. Next, `@php` is for use in `.blade.php` templates for quick PHP logic; you should be doing this Query in a Controller and passing the result forward. Finally, you never use `->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)` (or similar). You've got a few things to fix here.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: you are right thanks for helping